# Android add event to specific google calendar without "Make changes to events" permission

Tags: android, events, calendar, google-calendar-api

So I'm developing an android app for our team members rather than general users, and I want to let them add events to a specific google calendar for management purpose.

The old way of doing this is that I shared a calendar with team members using "make changes to events" permission, then after the calendar have been sync to android, my app can access it by some calendar provider code.

The problems are:
1. "make changes to events" permission makes everyone able to see or even delete everything on the management calendar.
2. I have to make sure everyone have some calendar app and have sync our management calendar, so my app can find it using calendar provider.

I was thinking that maybe I can setting my default management account into app (with some sort of protection), then add event to my calendar, so no shared calendar was involve, and the process is totally hidden from our members.
I thought google calendar api would help but can't find the right way to do it after lots of research.

I am kind of lost now. Am I on the right track or should I try some different way?
Any suggestion would help, thanks!

Comment: While adding invitees to the event, you can select the permission that invitee is allowed for that event. check this link http://oregonstate.edu/helpdocs/faq/how-do-i-change-permissions-my-google-calendar. This helps to resolve your use case.

Comment: Yeah I know that permission thing but it's too rough. https://goo.gl/bqwZlZ What I need is like "Author" or "Contributor" permission in the link. Thanks for replying anyway. @SGC